# Customised Word Cloud in two different colors in R

Tags: r, word-cloud

I am trying to create a word cloud in R, wherein I have a matrix with positive and negative words, however, I want to show positive and negative words in two different colors (say green and red). Can someone please help me on this. Thanks!

```
library(qdap)

x1 = x[a0]    

pol = polarity(x1)        
wc = pol$all[,2]          
val = pol$all[,3]         
p  = pol$all[,4]          
n  = pol$all[,5]          

positive_words = unique(setdiff(unlist(p),"-"))  # Positive words list
negative_words = unique(setdiff(unlist(n),"-"))  # Negative words list
total_words1 =cbind(positive_words,negative_words)

pos.tdm = dtm[,which(colnames(dtm) %in% total_words1)]
m = as.matrix(pos.tdm)
v1 = sort(colSums(m), decreasing = TRUE)

windows() # opens new image window
wordcloud(names(v1), v1, scale=c(4,1),1, max.words=100,colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
title(sub = "Words - Wordcloud")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You can choose the colors for each word by listing them in `colors` and then using `ordered.colors=TRUE`.  I am giving a simple example of just red and green words, but you could vary the shades of red and green by the frequency of the word.

```
Pos = read.table(text="Word    Count
Great       10
Good        25 
Fabulous    7",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

Neg = read.table(text="Word    Count
Bad         23
Stinks      5
Terrible    15",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

AllWords = rbind(Pos, Neg)
Colors = c(rep("green", nrow(Pos)), rep("red", nrow(Neg)))

wordcloud(AllWords $Word, AllWords $Count, 
        colors=Colors, ordered.colors=TRUE)
```

[image: WordCloud]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! This was very helpful and worked!! Just a follow-up, now the shape of my word cloud is not that visually looking good, any tips on how to improve it?

Comment: @Vishal - The placement  is partly random.  Try running it several times and save the ones that are nicest.